# Choosing endianness for new data formats

Tags: endianness

I need to create a new file format for use with multiple languages (including at least C++ & Java). The data being stored includes long lists of ints, and so I have to choose between little-endian and big-endian representation.  While it's clear that both options can be made to work, (using Java LittleEndianDataInputStream and the like), it's not clear which option is better in terms of not creating headaches for programmers down the road.

What are the criteria favouring little-endian or big-endian?

Answer (score 1):

Big-endian is the [network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  If for what ever reason you wished to send over a network socket instead of saving to a file and you used big-endian you could reuse some code.

Comment: Interesting point, though in this case the files will stay on single machines.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a textual format, like JSON. Just works, independent of endianness. Independent of word size. And parsers are available everywhere.

Comment: I am replacing an old format that proved to be too slow, so speed is an issue. Consequently text-based formats are out.

Comment: I'm curious - what types of operations is the app having to do that are "too slow" for just storing a list of int's using a modern and standard (if text-based) format?  Just one prototypical example would help me understand better.